# I cannot manually edit date fields before closing bracket in org-mode buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date, calendar

I am aware of the syntax for creating repeated tasks in org-mode, but for some reason I am now unable to manually edit the text of the "Scheduled" and "Deadline" date fields to do this, unless I do the workaround described below:

Example date field as it appears in my org-buffer:

    `**** TODO [#B] Order kitty litter
DEADLINE: <2017-02-07>`

Example date field as copied and pasted:

    `**** TODO [#B] Order kitty litter
DEADLINE: <2017-02-07 Tue + = >`

If I place the point before the closing angle bracket, as I would normally do to add repeating-event syntax, I cannot type. The only way I can edit this date field manually is if I first move the point to the opening angle bracket and destroy the syntax by adding a random character, e.g. `<a2017-02-07.`, which turns the filed into plain text. I can then move the point to the closing bracket, add the repeat syntax, and then remove the character I inserted to make it editable. But this is not behavior I have encountered before, so something must have changed in my config.

Can anyone point me to a config variable or other problem that might be the culprit? For example, where is that hidden `+ =` text before the closing bracket coming from?

Comment: Perhaps it is a major-mode or minor-mode keyboard shortcut that is being activated and you think it should be normal movement, but it is something special relating to org-mode.  Type `C-h k` and then do your movement that is problematic and see if it is actually a special org-mode function that gets activated or something normal.  Once you find out what function is being called, then you can deactivate that behavior or change it . . .  There is a special feature to overlay timestamps with a more eye catching appearance (perhaps that's it?): http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html

Comment: Do you have [custom timestamps](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html) enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled [org-toggle-time-stamp-overlays](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html) via `C-c C-x C-t`?

With this enabled you cannot place the cursor onto a timestamp anymore, only before or after.

Comment: This must have been it; I didn't enable it intentionally, but it may have showed up in one of the configurations I've borrowed from.